Wordpress: How to pull posts from categories from the URL
I'm on my first Wordpress project with a slight background in PHP.
I want to pull contents from the Posts with a category that matches a keyword from the URL to avoid creating all of the pages.
For example: I have a nested category that goes SHOPS-REGION-TYPE-shop. So I set the post URL to be /SHOPS/REGION/TYPE/shop. I basically want to create an archive page for all of the shop's when I go to /SHOPS/REGION/TYPE. Currently, the URL results in a 404 search page. I'm only able to achieve this by going to /category/SHOPS/REGION/TYPE. Is there a way to get rid of /category/ in the URL and still achieve the same goal?
I thought about creating a php page to do this initially, but I don't want to create pages for all the different types. Would there be a way to create one page that runs the same query to match a field from /TYPE/ in the URL if I went this route?
Thank you in advance.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
